# responsive background image and height of the text

Tags: text, responsive-design, height

I have background image for responsive div, so I calculated the height/width of the image and assigned padding in percentage. absolutely fine.

Now I need to add text inside the div, H1 and p tag. after adding these, div expanded vertically, overflow hidden is clipping the text.

How do I calculate the height of the texts and subtract the value from parent div to fit exactly.

Regards,
Gururaj

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
     var height = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
     document.write("width: "+width);
     document.write("height: "+height);
</script>
```

use this code to measure width and height, u can also use Jruler application. try media query for your CSS. not all screen have same value height and weight